# How can I get a channel width of WiFi under API level 23?

Tags: android-wifi

I am building an app that scans Wi-Fi APs and prints gathered information.

According to the Android docs, I can check [channel width of Wi-Fi after API level 23](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/ScanResult.html#channelWidth), which is Android M.

On the other hand, if I use API level lower than 23, I can't check that. You can see this by setting API level to 15, 21 or something in the link page above.

[image]

However, existing Wi-Fi device already supports 40, 80 and 160 MHz channels. The question is, that, how an Android device before Android M check whether an AP uses an wide channel?

Does a manufacturer put some special and customized API into vanilla Android?

Answer (score 0):

Without API 23, perhaps it's possible to come up with a table-driven approach that uses information found in [Wikipedia's list of WLAN channels](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_WLAN_channels#regulatory_tables5.0ghz).